# What happens when someone in the US clicks on a GB itunes URL?

Tags: app-store, itunes

If I provide a GB url itunes link to an app, say

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id586088546

what would happen if someone in outside the UK, say in the states clicks on that? would it work or would it redirect to a version on their regional app store?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question really belongs here but... I just clicked it and it took me to the UK store and didn't redirect me.  I am in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine and doesn't redirect. It keeps the "GB" and links on the page also point to the UK version of iTunes.